UiAutomator StaleObjectException immediately on finding object
I'm writing some UIAutomator2 tests.
I'm getting androidx.test.uiautomator.StaleObjectException when trying to access information about an object I've just found.
For example:
device.findOBject(By.focused(true)) gives me a UIObject2.
device.findObject(By.focused(true)).classNamethrows the StaleObjectException. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Is UIAutomator2 this unstable? Is there some fatal flaw the devs are making in their app that's causing this?
